# What is the optimal path I can use if question is posted on wrong portal

Tags: support, migration

I just want to know that if I posted a question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), somebody commented on that it is related to other portals of stack exchange for example  it is related to WordPress so https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is the right portal to post that question.

Now I want to know what is the optimal path I can use?

- Should I delete it on SO and post on wp.SE?
- or Is there any other way also possible like moving question from one site to another with in stack exchange network?

Answer (score 1):

Recommended approach is to **flag that post** and choose appropriate option so that site moderators can decide to migrate or not.

More details are available here:

[Can askers intentionally move their questions from one site to another?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102547/can-askers-intentionally-move-their-questions-from-one-site-to-another)

[How can I/Please migrate a question from site X to site Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148869/how-can-i-please-migrate-a-question-from-site-x-to-site-y)

> Should I delete it on SO and post on wp.SE ?

You can do that provided your post have not received any answers. As [Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles) has mentioned that "if you delete your question from the site where you originally posted it, you've wasted all of these people's attention". Before you post on WP.SE, please read its FAQ to check if your post is on-topic or not.

> Is there any other way also possible like moving question from one site to another with in stack exchange network

Yes other possibility is **voting to migrate** and **flagging** (if that site is not listed in migration list).

If you discover that you have posted on the wrong site soon after initial submission then delete your post. Else flag it for migration. There is no one optimal approach, it depends on the situation.

Comment: i think you missed the root of that question which is **optimal path **