# Significance of the users like 'user<random number>'

Tags: support, users, moderators, display-names

It's been more than a month since I have started using [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). It has these users with user names in the format of "user-random number". I have observed them in some of the stack activities, most of the time asking questions.

Does the moderators create them for their own purpose. If yes what purpose do they serve?

I mean a user is free to have any user name. But it's just a hunch that such users are actually moderators. I may be wrong; just need some clarification.

Comment: Every new users will get that name with their unique user id when they first registers on stackoverflow.! Even your display name was like this _user197093_ when you first started

Comment: sorry. Must've forgot about it. Should have correlated it with the user id in the same format at the top right corner or user profile. right?

Comment: Yup..exactly...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, these users aren't moderators. They could become diamond moderators via elections, though I don't think we have any [moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) who don't use a custom username at the moment, or they could earn enough reputation to get access to [community moderation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

`userXXXXXX` is just the default username someone gets when they first create an account.

Comment: `or they could earn enough reputation to get access to community moderation privileges.` [Well...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/6617/user281377)

Comment: yes. how much is enough? who decides that it is enough to be a moderator?

Comment: @HussainTamboli Users with more than 10,000 points get access to what we call moderation tools, but are _not_ moderators, moderators are either appointed by Stack Exchange (on Beta sites) or through elections (on graduate sites), and reputation is mostly irrelevant in either process. For more information see: [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Comment: thanks. It is totally irrelevant to the above question, but when I was doing `up` to more then 1 comments, stack gave a message that I can't up more than one comment within 5 sec. why is that?

Comment: @HussainTamboli So people won't upvote comments _like crazy_ ;P It's a very small wait, and although it can be annoying sometimes, just wait.