# Why can moderators review more than 40 close votes?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, moderators

Today a moderator [reviewed 60 close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats):

[image]

But the daily limit is 40. Is it just moderators who can do this? And why are they allowed to review 20 more?

I have checked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role), but it does not mention anything about reviewing more tasks.

Or is Bill special ;).

Comment: As a moderator Bill can close as many questions as he wants. The close votes review queue is so huge that I'm glad he does this :-).

Comment: I go over 40 on a pretty regular basis.  I'm surprised it took as long as it did for anyone to notice. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Oh I'd say more than a few of us notice! :)

Comment: I understand that moderators also get use of the corporate jet and keys to the executive bathroom.

Comment: The close vote review queue is mind-numbingly dull to work through so I think @BilltheLizard is doing a great job. A further question for Bill: the close votes would be immediately binding (due to being a diamond mod), but what about when you choose to leave it open? Is that also binding or does the question stay in the queue?

Comment: @slugster I'm not sure.  I just chose "leave open" on a question that had 4 close votes, then when I refreshed the question they were still there.  (This was just for testing. I then closed the question.)  I don't know if that means the question would stay in the queue for other people to review or not.

Comment: @slugster AFAIK “leave open” removes the question from the close queue, and starts the 4-day expiration ticker on the close votes. Moderators cannot erase the existing close votes (though they can simulate that by closing and reopening immediately after).

Comment: @Gilles Cheers for that, good to know for when I dive into the review queue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moderators don't have a limit for the number of questions they can close, nor a limit for the number of the questions they can review in the close review queue. I checked, and what reported in that queue is effectively the number of questions closed through the queue; it doesn't include the questions closed directly from the question page.