# Is it possible for moderators to review more than the daily limited count?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, moderators

W.K.T, any user(with more than 2k rep) can review 20 suggested edits per day.

Today I saw the newly appointed moderator [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) reviewed more than 20.

[image]

Is it possible for moderators to review more than the daily limited count?

If yes, can any moderators can do it at any time?

I didn't see this before.

Comment: `46 > 20` I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the powers conferred by the diamond.

Comment: @CodyGray, I can't find the answer there.

Comment: @CodyGray Not a dup - the answer is not in that post.

Comment: If it's not there already, it should be added. The FAQ questions are community wikis for a reason. Mad Scientist's answer is a good start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Moderators in general have an unlimited amount of flags, close votes, delete votes and also reviews.

Moderators are still subject to rate limits, but any other limits related  to moderation duties don't apply to diamond moderators.