# Question about issues on VPN

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I've lost 14 reputation points because and admin thinks that VPN is not about programming. It's incredible. This is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444805/is-ftp-on-vpn-possible (possibly 10k link).

Now I've understood the reason, but 14 point is a lot!

Comment: It's definitely not a programming question, but in theory it's about programming tools.... hm. The downvotes are maybe because it's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking, can you clarify? FTP through a VPN is definitely possible but you'll need a FTP server. I would suggest starting again with a more clear question, perhaps delete the downvoted one, and maybe consider posting on http://superuser.com instead - not sure

Comment: The admin deleted 8 point in this post and after have found onother past post and deleted other 4 point from there!!

Comment: I don't see how that's a programming question at all.

Comment: @Stefano: anyone (nearly) can vote on posts, and that's what removed rep in your case. No admin intervened.

Answer (score 16):

I think this might be directed at me.

1. I am not an admin (admins a.k.a. mods have a nice [shiny diamond ♦ after their name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role))
2. As [I already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444805/is-ftp-on-vpn-possible#comment30543857_20444805) that question has nothing to do with programming. Please check out our help sections: [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
3. It takes [five people from the community to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)
4. It takes another [three people to delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
5. I did not take 14 fake intarnetz moneyz (I did downvote your question though, but that [does not equal 14 fake intarnetz moneyz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work))
6. After deletion of a post the OP will get his / her fake intarnetz moneyz back

Conclusion: that question is offtopic (as already stated in the comments before closing and by showing the banner after closing) and the community (at least part of it) agreed.

---

FWIW you were pointing out other [offtopic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264239/use-vpn-to-connect-to-a-website/11264585) in the comments on your question asking why [those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625573/tunnelling-traffic-through-my-server-using-an-application/1625588#1625588) weren't closed and yours is. Have no fear, we the people have also successfully closed those questions. Thanks for pointing it out.

Also now with the help of a mod those questions are also deleted.

Comment: OK I've understand man. Please stop to talk me now

Comment: He can "talk" to you here as much as he wants to as long as he's not rude or breaking any other rule... You on the other hand are free to ignore him - but he's just trying to help you understand how this site works!

Comment: @ThiefMaster I am allowed to talk now? You've just opened Pandora's box. Now how are you going to explain this (allowing me to talk) to the other mods?

Comment: @PeeHaa Shiny broom > Shiny diamond