# How to find fake accounts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What will happen if someone create a fake account and use it to increase the reputation of his original account by up voting the questions and answers? Is there any mechanism available to find out these kind of accounts?

Comment: Yes. And the developers aren't going to tell you what the mechanism is to make it easier for you to circumvent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is such a mechanism, but it's only available to [moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) and SE employees.

When [voting fraud](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) is discovered, usually the main account is suspended and the secondary accounts removed. If the behavior persists, harsher measures (e.g. flogging) may be used.

Answer (score 1):

**For your first question:**

Yes your account gets suspended for for period of time(some mechanism is uesd);

**Is there any mechanism available to find out these kind of accounts?**

Yes there is but but i think i don't know the name(No one must be knowing as because of security reason or may be too difficult to understand)