# I have deleted my answer, but it shows that someone else did that?

Tags: bug, answers, deleted-answers

I have deleted my own answer, then I see below it:

deleted by Flexo♦ 1 min ago

who is Flexo♦? Why does it show that he has deleted my answer?

here: [Nginx Reverse Proxy non listening domain catch all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672562)

Comment: He's a mod. It could be that he beat you to the delete button.

Answer (score 9):

[Flexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) is a Stack Overflow moderator.  Your post was flagged for moderator attention by several other users because you posted a new question in the answer section to someone else's question.  Only answers should be posted there, not follow-up questions.  Moderators are routinely called upon to delete these kinds of posts.  Flexo must have deleted the question a moment before you did, so he's recorded as the person who deleted it.

Comment: related: [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)