# Accessing preferences as a moderator should not show email

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, preferences, pii

When accessing the preferences tab of a user profile from another user as a moderator, I see the following:

[image]

Unlike the other places where the user mail address is shown, it is shown by default without moderator interaction here. Usually there is an explicit second click required to show PII.

Viewing this tab also doesn't lead to an entry in the user history about a moderator accessing the email address, unlike all other actions on the user profile that would expose PII.

There's really no reason to show the mail address here at all for regular moderators, so it might be the easiest way to just not show it at all. Otherwise it should have the same click-through like everywhere else.

Comment: Why do moderators have access to this page?

Comment: @JanDvorak Editing the profile can be necessary to remove offensive content. Access to other parts of this are probably more a side-effect of this requirement.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Speaking of which, does the "my logins" page show something a mod shouldn't see?

Comment: How do you know my email address is `user@example.com`?! Flagged for revealing PII! :-P

Comment: @JanDvorak According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100153), they see what you see, except OpenId itself.

Comment: On the other hand, what's exactly the 'risks' of a non rogue moderator seeing this? I suppose we don't really need it unless we're trying to send a mod message  but I've occasionally used it to look at who the mail host for a persistant troll might be.

Comment: @JanDvorak Moderators can see the credentials associated with an account, and this is also one of the actions that is logged.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I would guess it's the rogue ones concerning us here

Comment: @MadScientist is this still as shown or has it changed?

Comment: @bad_coder I'm not a moderator anymore, no idea