# What information about users does SE software enable site moderators to see?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, moderators

How does the SE software protect community user privacy specifically wrt site moderators? For instance, are moderators provided user account information beyond what is posted in user network profiles?

If so, what additional information is provided to moderators?

Comment: This is addressed in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100153/377214) to our FAQ [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role), under the section "Actions affecting users".

Comment: The suggested duplicate does indicate that diamond moderators have access to confidential PII. It may be useful to discuss how it is used, when it is accessed, and whether that's appropriate, but the simple question of *what do they have access to*  has been addressed.

Comment: _"IP addresses that the account was accessed from"_ - Wouldn't a hash of the IP be sufficient? Why do they need the actual IP?