# What is the authority of moderators in defining the scope of a site?

Tags: discussion, moderation, scope, moderator-abilities

*Please read this as a neutral question. I'm asking and not trying to make a point.*

#### Though I'll start with a rant (for context)...

I recently ran into a situation that I found quite disheartening on one SE site.  After my question was closed as off-topic the moderator response explaining why left me much more frustrated.

Despite the technology being the core topic of the site, and me following documentation page that was on-topic, the moderator said that they believed the question ***might possibly*** be answerable on another community and therefore off-topic. This was despite the moderator admitting they didn't really know much about the subject of the question themselves.

So it was closed because:

- I, as the OP, couldn't prove my question was impossible to answer on *any* other SE site.
- Moderation seemed focussed on the possible answers much more than the question
- Moderation seemed focussed on possible answers despite the moderator not knowing the subject `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

---

I've known for some time that this particular site has some odd behaviour around marking questions as "off-topic".  It's always left me feeling a little reticent to post questions there, and that’s speaking as a relatively experienced SE user.

A quick check on the site's own meta showed at least four questions on off-topic closures that were discussed very recently.  Reading through them I don't think I'm the only one finding the implementation of their "house rules" a little too abrasive.

This latest interaction has left me pretty sure I don't want to go back there. I can't imagine a question for that site that I couldn't crowbar into a format acceptable elsewhere.

---

#### My question (quite separate from the context)

I think what concerned me most is the way that it seems one moderator (maybe more) are driving away users and souring a community through overzealous implementation of scope.

The moderation seems far more strict than declared on the site's own "what questions belong here" page.  In effect, I feel the moderator is redefining the scope of the site and I take evidence from the frustrations of other posters on the site's meta.

But I don't know which comes first.  Are moderators expected to read that scope and diligently follow it?  Or is a mismatch between that page and moderators behaviour little more than the moderators forgetting to update the page.

In other words, is the **definition** of a site's scope entirely in the hands of the moderators?

---

#### Further thoughts

I had previously believed that sites were largely community led, with community close votes being predominant.  I see on some smaller sites though that this is not always possible.  Close queues can be hard to staff with enough high-rep users to reach 3 or 5 votes.  Where that's the case, the moderator closures are much more obvious.

On the assumption that the moderator is overreaching their remit, there doesn't seem to be any mechanism for the community to bring moderators to account for their actions in this context.  One can only assume that the last resort is moderator elections.

I don't honestly know how effective that is.

In any case I'm simply unsure on whether it is even possible for a moderator to overstep their reach.  In the political world, there's little to stop politicians creating laws as they chose.  It's not clear to me if SE gives the same level of authority to moderators on election.  Are they elected law makers or elected judges?

---

*I deliberately didn't mention which site.  I absolutely do not want this question to become personal.*

Comment: "In other words, is the definition of a site's scope entirely in the hands of the moderators" - that's some weird thing to claim. I'll throw in some other thoughts: moderators are community-elected, which by definition means that community approves of what these mods inclined to do. Topics are probably mostly community-ruled. Like, what actually made you think that moderators decide the topics? They are also hardly the ones who close the most questions, since it's most certainly mostly done by regular users

Comment: @nicael Lots to unpic there. I think this because I witness a fair few questionable closures compared to the site's declared scope. Some smaller sites don't have the numbers of high-rep users monitoring the close queues and so struggle to get 3 or 5 votes from community, where mods go round with a big mod button... their effect can be way more significant on some sites. Even in some larger sites re-open queues are often understaffed so if a mod closes it, it's closed. I see no mechanism to bring mods to account on their personal interpretation of scope regardless of what the community wants.

Comment: have you tried disputing closure by raising a question on per-site meta?

Comment: @nicael I document the (paraphrased) mod's response in my rant in this question. Honestly it boils down to their personal interpretation of scope and they seem wholly convinced they're in the right.  It was their meta response that led me to become so concerned.  IMO you shouldn't moderate the potential answers but the question, except in the case of "opinion based".

Comment: That mod is not only one who decide the scope of the site. If you publish your claims on per-site meta and community will wholly support you, I doubt the mod would resist. Have you asked anybody else except that mod?

Comment: @nicael It's there for all to see on the site's meta.  I'm not interested in expending energy on it with them further.  It's already enough to make me quit the site.  I have better things to do with my time than tell moderators they're wrong when they won't listen.  I appreciate your concern though.

Comment: I actually believe that mostly all that you’ve stated could be resolved if that community would be more active (which applies to a lot of communities). The problem in this case is neither in moderators that are somehow are immune to community judgement as you may have thought, nor in the absence of an arbitrary post-election mod-judging system, it’s just the community which is not engaged, which thus leads to moderators *having* to do many things singlehandedly, while barely anyone helping them to moderate the site

Comment: You should define what exactly upsets you. If we emphasize on the fact that moderators are the only who moderate the said community because of low overall engagement rate, what do you propose then? To remove the only ones who seems to regularly care of community? That’s chaos guaranteed for no good reason

Comment: @nicael you're not wrong.  There's a vicious circle with this one. Random closures like this are a terribly fast way to drive away users. That's exact opposite of encouraging community engagement. On the wider internet you see sites fail due to collapsed user base, or just spiral inward on themselves forming tight cliques. Bad moderation can really kill a site. I don't have a proposal though, it's why I ask the question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were clearer about exactly what happened. (Diamond) "moderators" here are elected exception handlers. Users with enough reputation can "curate" (sometimes, ambiguously, "moderate")--take actions like comment, vote up or down, edit, and vote to close or to delete, etc. It's not clear just how you are using "moderator". Please be clear about what actions were taken or what privileges you are talking about when you talk about them. PS Please research before considering asking a question. What did your research show about how sites determine what is on-topic?

Comment: @philipxy they're talking about diamond mods, which I think is generally assumed when talking about mods. As for why they don't give all the details of the triggering event, see their last sentence. I think the asker is clear _enough_ about the event, given that they want to ask a more general question that is not specifically about that event. As for their research, they at least know about the on-topic page given their sentence: "_Or is a mismatch between that page and moderators behaviour little more than the moderators forgetting to update the page._"

Comment: @philipxy I wholly disagree with your stylistic guidance for reasons too long for comoments. I deliberately wanted this to be a question about the generic responsibly/ capability of (diamond) moderators. Discussing if my original post was on or off topic for the site in question would be way off topic here on this site and this question.

Comment: "Please read this as a neutral question" - I tried but you make it impossible. You don't ask this in neutral way, rather a pure rant way. That's fine, I do get the frustration, but claiming otherwise is just wrong.

Comment: Re your rant: if those are indeed the closing reasons, I believe them to be unfair as well. A question should not be closed (even judged) based on its (potential) answers; and off-topicness is not defined by scopes of other sites (it can, probably must, be taken into account, but is no reason on its own for closing). Not what you're asking for, but just to say I empathize with your situation.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars They're not claiming, they're suggesting :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars How so? what point do you ultimately believe I'm trying to make? I can't disguise my frustration, I've not really tried to. I honestly don't know if the mod is overstepping their authority by redefining the scope or if this is somehow the function of their role. I clearly the mod's behaviour in this situation was wrong, but that doesn't answer my question of whether it's within the rules.

Comment: @Joachim what about Stack Overflow's "recommendation request" close reason? That one seems to be about the potential answers.

Comment: @PhilipCouling it all boils down to "My question was closed, it is unfair".

Comment: What do you mean by *"following documentation page that was on-topic"*? E.g., are one or more words missing? E.g., *"following* ***a*** *documentation page that* ***it*** *was on-topic"* ("it" referring to the question, not the documentation page)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Trying not to point to the specific site... the title of the documentation page I was following was literally "do <thing> for <core technology>" where the "core technology" was the core subject of the SE site.  Very hard for me to see any way that discussion of the documentation page's words would have been off topic.  Feel free to find a better wording

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Comment: @AugustoVasques that Q&A seems to focus more on mod privileges instead of non-privilege-based roles. Defining scope is much more high-level (I think). Others have already mentioned that defining the scope of a site is done in Area51 and then carried on by all members of the site's community on their meta site.

Comment: The question seems to be confusing moderators' role in **defining** scope with that of **interpreting** it once defined.

Comment: @Tetsujin Discussion of what that distinction looks like, how to tell them apart, what stops a moderator mixing the two and / or what to do about if a moderator does confuse the two would all make the basis of good answers here.  I do believe I've witnessed a moderator unapologetically crossing that boundary, and it left me wondering if the boundary even exists for moderators... so I wrote this question.

Comment: I'm not sure I could make it into an answer. I know different stacks handle things differently [of course]. Some will slap anything closed for the slightest reason, others are more lenient. idk how we could persuade the mods on each to interpret their interpretations any other way. Meta doesn't change minds, only single results, in my experience.

Comment: Related: [Is "the community" an arbiter or an authority of "belonging" on the site?](/q/386302) (asking about community instead of mods)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a moderator, I basically have the same abilities as 3-5 users in a trench coat, and ideally the ability to shape/opinions via meta. For the most part I *interpret* and *help enforce* the rules rather than unilaterally define the scope of the site.

> I, as the OP, couldn't prove my question was impossible to answer on any other SE site.

Well, as a moderator or closevoter that doesn't really matter to us. Our consideration, as it should be for most of the folks closevoting, is whether it’s on topic for *us* primarily. If it’s a great question migration, it might be an option, but this is a way to save a *spectacularly* good question mostly.

> Moderation seemed focussed on the possible answers much more than the question

While people are focused on the question, people come here for the answers. And, to take an example off [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), a question ends up being a shopping question on account of its answers, it’s a shopping question even if it’s not the intent.

> Moderation seemed focussed on possible answers despite the moderator not knowing the subject ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Amusingly enough - I'm not a subject matter expert in 'all' of the scope of the sites I moderate. And sometimes I forget enough that I'm no longer an [SME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) in something I was an SME of. I can't be expected to keep away from, say, macOS questions because I've literally had more time on [HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX) and [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) systems. What I *am* is someone who is reasonably familiar with the site.

> A quick check on the site's own meta showed at least 4 questions on off-topic closures that were discussed very recently. Reading through them I don't think I'm the only one finding the implementation of their "house rules" a little too abrasive.

Meta discussion of off-topic questions is The Way. It gives the *community* an opportunity to review a decision and vote accordingly.

> This latest interaction has left me pretty sure I don't want to go back there. I can't imagine a question for that site that I couldn't crowbar into a format acceptable elsewhere.

So the question might be - was it crowbarred into the 'problem' site?

> I think what concerned me most is the way that it seems one moderator (maybe more) are driving away users and souring a community through overzealous implementation of scope.

This might depend on what's the exact situation. I've been here a while, and outside some fairly epic dumpster fires, scope adjustments are unpopular. A good chunk of my early reputation on Super User from things that could be closed now - and I adjusted to how some rules were interpreted. That said, in a *healthy* community - well, there are *many* voices, and that 'one' voice isn't more important than another one shouldn't be true.

I'd want to look at *what* exactly the implementation of the scope is, try to understand the reasoning, and try to figure the best option for the community. Consider things like homework dumps, 'write me a thing to do this please?' and so on.

> Close queues can be hard to staff with enough high-rep users to reach 3 or 5 votes. Where that's the case, the mod closures are much more obvious.

This is... a bigger problem, much more complex and needs another wall of text like this one. I suspect it’s a combination of broader community turnover, often the lack of incentives to look at the queues or lack of high rep users. It’s more of a community growth and sustainment problem than a moderation problem.

> Beyond elections there doesn't seem to be any mechanism for the community to bring mods to account for their actions in this context. One can only assume that the last resort is moderator elections.

Meta, meta and more meta. There's value both in generalised posts on policy and specifically making a case for specific posts. This *is* a moderation problem, with effective meta use being an acquired skill, but also a UX problem (people can't find meta) and a community growth and sustainment problem.

Comment: I appreciate the thought you've given to this. What jumps out to me is this point about moderating for possible answers vs moderating the question.  Sure we have the "opinion based" close reason, which makes sense from the perspective of avoiding flame wars. But from a scoping point of view I don't see any way that a question could end up *"being a shopping question on account of its answers"* without the content of the question involving some kind of "where to buy" or "how to acquire". Perhaps you've seen something I haven't. Do you have any examples (hypothetical or concrete)?

Comment: I feel like hardware recs and software recs on Super User are a great example see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2991/what-is-the-difference-between-shopping-recommendations-and-hardware-rec-tagged and https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9215/when-are-software-recommendation-answers-not-an-answer . These might work better if you're asking about a problem and a *class* of hard/software rather than specific recs

Comment: Oh I see. If I may categorise... these examples point to fairly specific forms of questions that are known to elicit bad results. Rather like the "opinion based" close votes, regulars just know that a particular form of question must remain off topic because of the trouble it causes.  In a way I don't think that disproves my belief that questions should not be moderated [individually] based on their potential answer. It's noticeable that that [this answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2992/112499) discusses features of the question that are problematic, not features of potential answers.

Comment: Those were ok once, then needed scope changes

Comment: Thanks. Do moderators have the keys to change the stated scope page for the site when scope does change?  If not, who does?

Comment: Actually changes involve a meta post, and getting the community team to make the actual changes

Answer (score 6):

: *Community builder hat on* :

Unfortunately, I think that commenters nailed it.  It comes down to having an active enough community.  With that said, I've certainly seen communities where one dedicated zealot was able to turn things around. If this is enough to make you quit the site, that's probably not you.... and that’s totally okay!  Being a zealot is not for everyone.  It's draining, and tiresome, and you've likely got other stuff to do to contribute elsewhere on the network.

But until such a zealot comes along and manages to stir up the community on the site, I'm afraid that there's not much hope there.

: *switch hats, VP of community hat* :

Some of this leads to the question of whether we would ever get involved (we being staff, [CMs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) here).  The answer is "probably not".  You haven't said anything that makes me think we have the right to - you haven't alleged abuse by the moderators, or anything of that nature.  Failing that, our default stance (and my personal preference) is to stand by and—when we have the opportunity and the staffing to do it—to attempt to bring more folks onto network sites.  But there's a ton of work to be done right now, and community building/evangelism isn't something we've been able to invest resources in lately, and honestly I don't think that's likely to change in the immediate future.

Now, we've certainly (as a company) invested in areas that we hope will positively affect site growth, through various features, for instance. But that's a long on-ramp usually. By the time a feature deploys, and word gets out about it (or more likely, organic traffic finds it and likes it enough to stick around), substantial time has elapsed.  Using feature development to drive community growth is absolutely not a quick win. It is, however, a sustainable choice, where quick-fix membership drives are typically not.

Which takes us back to the zealot...

Comment: From what I read elsewhere moderators remain in post until they step down, become inactive, or commit some serious violation of SE rules such as abuse. I respect SE staff's position in taking no action in this type of problem directly. But view this in light of an inability for communities to unseat moderators; there's no fixed terms or reelections... this means plain old bad moderators are left in place with nobody both capable and willing to do anything about it. Even as a "zealot" I don't see what I could do to change the behaviour of a mod who's clearly entrenched in their own view.

Answer (score 6):

In answer to your question:

> In other words, is the **definition** of a site's scope entirely in
> the hands of the moderators?

I would say that, once a site has exited [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) (where initial scope is defined), the definition of a site's scope is almost entirely in the hands of that site's per-site Meta users.  That Meta community proposes, and via voting, tries to demonstrate consensus around changes in the scope of a site.  A moderator plays no greater role in this than any other engaged Meta user because their vote in this regard is identical.

Consensus can often be hard to achieve, and I suspect that what you perceive as a moderator unilaterally defining the scope of a site may be no more than them trying to interpret community consensus on the site's scope.  As an engaged user, a moderator may not have voted with what appears to be consensus on a particular scope item, but you should not expect to see them super-voting to close questions as out of scope for any reason that consensus indicates as being in scope.  If they do, then you should raise that on their per-site Meta using an objective description of where and why you think they misinterpreted the site scope.  Moderators are expected to be willing to always explain their decisions.

Close (and re-open) votes are not the mechanism to define site scope, they are the community's mechanism to assess questions against the scope that they have defined.