# Why did all the comments under my answer disappear?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments, deleted-comments

I have an answer to one of the questions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62869060/2183775)) and many comments were there. Now every comment disappeared while the comments under the other responses are still there.

What might have happened? Is it a Stack Overflow bug or someone deleted them intentionally?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) - specifically under the headings **Who can delete comments?** and **When should comments be deleted?** in [the canonical answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/341145)

Comment: Next time, please ask about site-specific things on that site's meta. In your case, since you are asking about [so], that would be https://meta.stackoverflow.com. This site, https://meta.stackexchange.com/, is the meta site for the entire network, so if your question only pertains to one site, then it should not be asked here.

Comment: Thanks Sam Onela and terdon.

Answer (score 10):

The comments were flagged by members of the community and removed. The comments were removed between Nov. 2020 and Feb. 2023 as the flags came in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question how do you know that? Do you have more privilege to see things like this than me?

Comment: @Pistaatortenesz maybe [that moderator badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy) on their profile has something to do with it .... (there also is a [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189) about moderators)