# Closing questions on StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, search, vote-to-close

My interpretation of being able to vote to close questions is to mark duplicates, spam etc and generally keep things nice and tidy.

**As a question needs 5 votes to be closed is there anyway that I am able to view questions that have at least one close vote and are still waiting for the full 5 votes.**

Not that I want to encourage people to jump on the bandwagon and just go around closing any old question.

If a question really is a duplicate and only has 2 votes - what happens if no one else votes to close it? Does it just sit there forever until someone stumbles upon it?

I don't even know if this is really an issue as I have no idea how many questions are waiting for the full 5 votes and if they really should be closed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10k users have the ability to see all questions sorted by how many votes to close are around, according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users/4576#4576). This is probably exactly to avoid, as you say, bandwagon voting. So I guess, currently, one just has to wait until one has sufficient reputation.

To wit, though, close votes decay after... 4 days, I believe it was. So you can always just restrict your gandering to all posts within 4 days. Which is of course a huge number over at SO, but there's nothing currently available to filter that number when it comes to pending close votes.

Comment: hmm... I don't think it's 4 days, you can see older close votes on the moderator tools

Comment: @Juan: Those are from questions that have been closed and reopened.

Comment: @Jon, not really but @Grace is right that they expire, check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/54447/how-to-see-newest-questions-for-all-of-interesting-tags, it has no close votes, yet it appears to have 2 on the las 14 days list (and it doesn't appear on the last 7 days list). I think it shows votes casted in the last 30 days maximum, but they expire before that

Comment: @Juan: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/54447/revisions

Comment: lol @Jon, I will shut up now...

Answer (score 3):

This is already a feature for 10k users, so you'll have to get 10k to have this feature.

We get a Tools section that, among other things, lists all questions with close votes within a certain range of time (today, past 2 days, 7 days, 14 days, 30 days). For close votes, only the first 3 ranges are useful because close votes decay after 4 days. For a question to be closed, 5 close votes have to be cast within a span of 4 days (which isn't necessarily 4 days after the question is asked).

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this feature will be implemented for users lower than 10k.

The purpose of the 3k tools are **not** to deputize the users into becoming *de facto* moderators. They are designed to recognize that people who have spent so much time on the site should be able to help clean up the communtiy if they see fit.

It is not a call to arms nor vigilantism. The 10k tools, on the other hand, are built to recognize that these users are (hopefully) repsponsible and community involved enough that we want to encourage them to go out of their way to act as partial moderators.

The 3k users should just help out when they are *on* a question, but there's no need for them to spend extra time simply moderating. They should use that time to go outside, see their families, or get some work done.

The 10k users have none of those things.

Comment: 10k users have no outside, no families, and no work to get done?  Well, it does seem like it some days :D