# access to moderation tools

Tags: discussion, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the moderation tools available to high-reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users)

What does `access to moderation tools` mean?

I have rep> 10k at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165520/prasoon-saurav) but I have no idea what *powers* have I got now :P.

Someone please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new link in the top bar called [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/) that links to all of them. There's a nice summary of them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users/4576#4576), but if you already have 10k you can just explore for yourself :)