# All-time ranking in SO

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to see a way to browse the most upvoted / downvoted question (or answer), the question with more views, an so on...

Is there a way to do it in SO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: For answers, there's always [SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com). I know for a fact [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is the highest voted answer ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the data explorer. For example:

- [Most upvoted posts](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/571/highest-voted-posts)
- [Most downvoted posts](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/572/lowest-voted-posts)
- [Most viewed questions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/573/most-viewed-questions)

Alternatively, the [10k tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users) provide such lists (only for the last 30 days, though).

Comment: The 10k tools only provide such lists from within a certain period of time (up to 30 days), not all-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [API](http://stackapps.com) to query all of the things that you ask for.

The onlything available right now through the site is the [votes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) where you can see the questions with the most votes.