# How do I vote to delete an answer?

Tags: support

I saw an answer with invalid links and flagged it.  With the following comment:

```
Both of these links are no longer valid. – 7 hours ago
```

I then got the following comment from a moderator

```
declined - With over 10K rep, you can a) vote to delete or b) edit the links out yourself.
```

I'm happy to do so, but I don't know how.  How do I vote to delete an answer?

Comment: You can only vote to delete an answer if it has negative votes. What score did the answer have?

Comment: It had 5 votes from when it was written but the links had since all gone away.

Comment: So it was at +5? In that case the first reason was incorrect - however the second was still correct.

Comment: @Scrooge Really? That's not mentioned in the FAQ. *looks for a source*

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1131452/215752

Comment: @JeremyBanks http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user (the mod apparently confused that with 10k abilities)

Comment: I feel so teased -- finally I get to 10k only to hear about how I should be doing things I can't do before 20k :)

Comment: Ah - my mistake [it's at 20K](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) you get the ability to delete negatively scoring answers. The mod was doubly wrong then :)

Comment: BTW, that flag was invalid, because the answer still makes sense without the links. You might edit out the last sentence, which is worthless without the link (even better would be to find where the target of that link has moved!). If the answer had consisted solely of links and had been useless without following the links, then a “not an answer” flag would have been justified (even if the links had not been dead).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion that I caused in the message.  The main point here really isn't that you can delete content (but yes, that *was* a mistake on my part), but rather to convey to you that a post that has two dead links **does not** warrant moderator attention.  There are a number of options at varying rep levels (one of which I presented was valid, edit it) which are available to you.  If the entire Stack Exchange ecosystem depended on the moderators to handle editing, voting to close/delete and all the other things that is afforded to users with rep, the sites would be crippled.

Comment: My $0.02 - if the answer consists **only** of those dead links and you can't find any mirror or alternative to the links, then flag it asking to delete the answer - otherwise remove the links yourself leaving "removed dead links" edit comment or replace them with live links if you can find such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently the moderator was confused: 10k users can't vote to delete answers, [that's a 20k privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user). As described in the [mod tools FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users), 10ks only have the ability to vote to delete questions that have been closed for two days.

Comment: The moderator was doubly confused. The delete link only appears when the answer has a negative score.

Comment: And only when the answer is not accepted.