# Questions are not properly sorted by close votes in 10k tools page

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, 10k-tools, sorting

In my moderation (10k) tools screen, on the "close" tab, I see this when I expand the "Most Votes" section:

> [image: Questions out of order]

Notice that the questions are not listed in order of number of close votes, as they should be according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4576/300411):

> The **close** category has views relating to questions that have been or are being closed or reopened:
>
> - Most close votes, sorted by number of votes

This is true even if I click the "sort by close reason" link and then click the "sort by close votes" link.  It's also true for all time selections (30d, 14d, 7d, 2d, today).

It does not appear to be related to caching either: the question with 3 votes is a much more recent entry into the close vote queue than ones both below and above it.

For me, the numbers immediately update when the number of close votes changes: I have found no discrepancy between the number shown on the tools screen and the number shown on the questions themselves.  Furthermore, when I apply a close vote, and check the tools screen 30 seconds later, the counter has updated to reflect my new close vote.

Comment: This is 10k-tools, right? I don't see that problem on ELL; it appears to be sorting just fine.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Correct, 10k tools.

Answer (score 3):

On Ask Ubuntu I'm experiencing a slightly different problem, which apparently is not really with the sorting of the questions and rather with the caching of the number of pending close votes:

[image: screenshot]

Opening both questions and checking the amount of close votes manually shows that the questions are both sitting at 4 close votes, despite the first one only showing 2 pending close votes (and the same goes for 10 of the questions above the first one, all showing 3 pending close votes but actually sitting at 4 close votes).

So on Ask Ubuntu the questions are sorted correctly, but indeed there's a problem with the caching of the numbers of pending close votes shown.

Comment: Good thought, but for me, that's not the case.  I click the links, and each question has the same number of votes appearing as is shown on the tools page.

Comment: @Nathaniel You sure? Because I've checked 10 questions above the first one in the screenshot (all displaying 3 close votes) and all of them are sitting at 4 as well.

Comment: Right now it shows 4,3,4,3,4, with the two threes being [this](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46246/21576) and [this](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2220/21576), which at this moment both show 3 on their question pages.  The ones showing four are correct also (votes haven't expired or been retracted).

Comment: @Nathaniel Ok, I see, I've changed my answer. I'll leave it here since it seems closely related to the issue you're describing.