# Why can 10k users see the so-called "deleted" posts?

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts

Since *deleted* posts are visible to 10k users why isn't the button called *hide* or the post **really** deleted?

What is the reason that 10k users can still see them? Isn't the purpose of deleting something to actually delete it?

Comment: We could be mistaken. Some of us around here are human ...

Comment: We can have a debate about wording but for anyone < 10K deleted really means deleted. Calling it hide would be confusing as well

Comment: lastly, not much is *really* deleted on SE. Most things are only logically deleted/hidden. The only things that come to mind are redactions of posts and maybe 1-rep user accounts that are spam nuked.

Comment: @rene if this is so then it would make much more sense to call _hide_ or _disable_ and gray it out. Giving someone an option to delete something and then don't delete it after all is very deceiving.

Comment: How should I read the downvotes here? Is this a bad question or what is it that you want to say by hitting the downvote button?

Comment: There's two possible reasons I can think of... firstly, we have a pretty comprehensive [FAQ on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) so some may be downvoting because they consider this lacking research... When it comes to meta, I'm not a huge fan of this practice but... also, on meta downvotes on Feature Requests are used to indicate disagreement with the request... this often leaks over into discussions.

Comment: If the FAQ doesn't answer your question, please feel free to clarify what information you feel is missing and we can try to address that. :)

Comment: see also: [What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4565/165773)

Comment: When you *delete* a file from a computer, it's possible to *undelete* it—and deleted files can be seen by people who run the right utilities. Nobody would say that the word *delete* should be replaced by *hide*. To qualify the normally recognized word *delete* in a way that means something cannot be undeleted, we would instead say *permanently delete*.

Comment: @JasonBassford well, this is not the best comparison because there is a huge difference; the deleted file is actually gone! It is not hidden within the folder that contained it before but it's moved to the bin and not even an admin can see it anymore. You can restore it but eventually you can delete it.

Comment: @john-doe No, you're wrong. The file is not actually gone. Technically, it exists where it always did. It's not moved anywhere—it remains at exactly the same location as before. What happens is that its entry in the *table of contents* is removed, so that it's no longer visible in a directly listing. But the data, itself, is *not* gone. Removing its entry from the table of contents (and not touching the data itself) could be considered the same as *hiding* it. (If using your interpretation.)

Answer (score 8):

10K-ers, moderators and OP's can see deleted posts so they are available for moderation purposes.

There are a few reasons posts get deleted, either by clicking the delete link or because the Roomba got it. Red flagged posts also get deleted and hidden (thanks Catija) from direct view.

Users > 10K rep have access to the moderation tools and one of the lists there is recently deleted posts. This allows trusted users to audit the deletion of content and react to removal of anything of value, either by editing it into shape, undelete vote or discuss removal on meta.

Most posts that get deleted are not worth recovering but we can't rule out upfront that some might overlook a good post or some might even abuse it (delete your homework question for example after receiving an answer).

(almost) Nothing on the SE network is permanent deleted. Once you've posted content you gave SE also a license to publish your work. It does that by keeping everything you post in their databases. Being deleted is just another state a post can be in, much like closed. The difference being that deleted posts are only shown to those who are trusted to salvage a missed pearl.

I'm not sure if *hide* would be a better kind of wording then delete does now. I don't think it would make a difference in how easy or difficult the actual feature can be understood by new or seasoned users.
 As for the grayed out option: we already do that for seriously down voted answers.

Comment: To me, "Hide" implies that it's still visible to everyone who might wish to see it. I think of heavily downvoted posts as being "hidden" by greying them out. For *most* users on a site, "Deleted" posts *are* deleted. The percentages of users with accounts who can see deleted posts, not to mention users who are viewing the sites passively, is incredibly small.

Comment: @Catija I get that distinction but hidden and deleted both mean *not visible* to me as a non-native speaker. Let the language lawyers from ELU.se chime in on this and correct my thinking ...

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your answer. My comment was intended to be more... supplemental. :) Also, of users on SO with <150 rep, only 3% have 10k... now, that's still >15k users but when you're looking at 10 million registered accounts, it's tiny. We do also actually "hide" the content of flag deleted posts from view by 10k users. :P

Comment: I'll virtually accept your answer because I'm not happy about how many downvotes I already got for this question. It's very frustrating to ask anything here.

Comment: @john-doe I virtually accept your vote then. Take care.