# Moderators shouldn't be able to view deleted posts

Tags: discussion, moderator-abilities, deleted-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should 10k rep users view self-deleted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/why-should-10k-rep-users-view-self-deleted-answers)

I don't think moderators should be able to view deleted posts. There are legitimate reasons for deleting something, such as if you accidentally post information you shouldn't have. What reasons are there for moderators   needing to view deleted posts?

Comment: Why not just flag for moderator attention or mail the team to get your specific post removed? Keeping deleted posts can be helpful while considering the flow a question and it's answers went through.

Comment: There should be a way to flag posts that you want permanently deleted, even if the result is a post which says "flagged as permanently deleted". You say you want to consider the flow a question and its answers went through... but you're artificially constricting that flow.

Comment: This feels like a duplicate to me: [Why should 10k rep users view self-deleted answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/why-should-10k-rep-users-view-self-deleted-answers)

Comment: FYI: If you edit your post in the first 5 minutes after posting it, it's not a part of the revision history and no one will be the wiser.  After that you need to email team@stackoverflow.com to have a dev remove it from the database.

Comment: Why did this get -10? Did I saw something offensive? I realize its a dupe, but since when does that warrant -1?

Answer (score 8):

The license says it all. When you posted it, it got loose. Even if you 'delete' it, other can vote to undelete it. If you posted something confidential, you need to email the team and ask them nicely to wipe it out.

Answer (score 6):

> what possible reason could moderators have for needing to view deleted posts?

I'm not sure why nobody actually answered this part yet. I'll assume by "moderators" you mean "10k users", since all you need is 10000 rep to view deleted posts, you don't need to be a diamond mod. The reason 10k users can view deleted posts is they can [vote to undelete them](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), as the natural counterpart to their ability to delete questions (just as 3k users can vote to close/reopen). They need to be able to see the question to know if they want to vote to undelete it

So not only is your post visible to 10k users, but if they vote to undelete it it could actually become visible to everyone again, which is why (as several other people have said) you should e-mail team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to remove it from the database entirely

Comment: Nobody answered it, because it is answered in the dupe.

Comment: "they should be able to view it because they can vote to undelete it" isn't really an answer.... that begs the question.. why can they vote to undelete it?

Comment: @Mark Because they can delete questions, and it would be bad if that were irreversible. If you mean why can they undelete self-deleted posts, sometimes people delete their own question when there's nothing wrong with it, either once they figure it out or if they don't get an answer fast enough

Comment: @Michael: If it was a worthy question, someone will re-ask it down the road.

Comment: @Mark Why should they need to? Particularly if the question was already solved, and now the answers are lost too because the question asker doesn't understand how SO works

Comment: @Michael because I think the pros outweigh the cons.

Answer (score 2):

I think they should be able to view deleted posts...I'm not sure if there is, but perhaps for a certain period before being permanently deleted...30 days for example...indefinitely probably isn't that useful.